# Is it possible to use same static variable with different values in the list<class>?

Tags: c#, static

Is it possible to use same static variable with different values in the list? I know the code is better without the static variable if I want to use different parameters. These are class' variables I use.

```
public class book : IEquatable<book>


public string name { get; set; }

public string author { get; set; }

public static string themeName { get; set; }

public static List<book> allTheBooks = new List<book>();

public int bookID { get; set; }
```

Constructor

```
public book(string bookName, string bookAuthor, string theme, int bookID)

{

    this.name = bookName;

    this.author = bookAuthor;

    this.bookID = bookID;

    themeName = theme;

    allTheBooks.Add(this);

}
```

Later in the code I create the books with following values

```
    book book1 = new book("Cooking 3", "Chef the Wrapper", "Cooking", 0);
    book book2 = new book("Modeling Models", "Matt McModel", "Fashion", 1);
    book book3 = new book("100 different ways to fry", "Gorgon Fryman", "Cooking", 2);
    book book4 = new book("Sea Sharp", "Unknown", "Coding", 3);
```

Right now every book's theme is Coding because of the static. I can give more code if demanded.

Sorry for typos, I'm not native English speaker. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well yes, `themeName` shouldn't be static. This has nothing to do with the fact that you're putting things in a list. It's not that "every book's theme is Coding" - it's that there's no such thing as "an individual book's theme".

Comment: As an aside, I'd very strongly urge you to start following .NET naming conventions.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for the fast answer. I was just wondering if is it possible to use same static var without changing all the others under the same static. List example wasn't probably the best example I could've give. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: There's no such thing as "all the others". You have *exactly one static variable* regardless of whether you have 0 books or 100. If you want one variable per book, you want an instance field.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.